# How to correctly set a circle imageView with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

im trying to make a circle imageprofile, like the profile image of instagram/whatsapp. Right now my code seems to work, but i did it in 2 different ways and both works, so i want to know which one is the best

**First way:**

```
profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.width / 2
profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

**Second way**

```
profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.width / 2
profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Also i would like if someone can explain me about "clipToBounds" and "maskToBounds", what they do. Thanks!

Comment: You can check about `clipsToBounds` and `masksToBounds`  :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177775/how-is-the-relation-between-uiviews-clipstobounds-and-calayers-maskstobounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clipsToBounds is a boolean value that determines whether subviews are confined to the bounds of the view.
Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds of the receiver. If set to NO, subviews whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value is NO. 
**Basically, this thing plays with the view's property.**

Whereas masksToBounds is a boolean indicating whether sublayers are clipped to the layer’s bounds.**And this thing plays with the layer of the view.**

Answer (score 0):

The way that I always do it, specifically in a situation where I want to show a profile picture in my application, I use this code:

```
profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImage.frame.size.width / 2;
profileImage.clipsToBounds = true;
```

This is what I would recommend to do!

Comment: OP Not asking for code. OP asking for which code is batter and why we have to use like this. OP already defined that code is working fine.

Comment: thanks, its good to know that other people use the same code to make circle images! thanks!