# Swift - Add an Image to a rounded View

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom view with corner radius and shadow, and I'm trying to add an image inside it. The image should be inside the rounded area. But I'm getting a black area in the view, where the image should be, (or the image as an square, without round corners, on my last attempt). How can I add this image?

The wrong result I'm getting:

[image]

My code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class RoundedSquareView: UIView {
  var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer!
  @IBInspectable var image: UIImage! = UIImage()

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if shadowLayer == nil {
      shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
      shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 14).cgPath
      shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

      shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
      shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
      shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10.0)
      shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
      shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 10

      layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
    }

    let imgLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let myImage = image.cgImage
    imgLayer.frame = bounds
    imgLayer.masksToBounds = true
    imgLayer.contents = myImage
    imgLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 14).cgPath
    imgLayer.cornerRadius  = 14
    layer.addSublayer(imgLayer)
  }

}
```

**EDIT:**

The expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a simple extension.  Here's an example:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func render(with radius: CGFloat) {

        // add the shadow to the base view
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 10

        // add a border view for corners
        let borderView = UIView()
        borderView.frame = self.bounds
        borderView.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        borderView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.addSubview(borderView)

        // add the image for clipping
        let subImageView = UIImageView()
        subImageView.image = self.image
        subImageView.frame = borderView.bounds
        borderView.addSubview(subImageView)

        //for performance
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 10).cgPath
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
myImageView.image = image
myImageView.render(with: 10)
```

Obviously you can add as many parameters as you want to the extension, set defaults, break it into separate methods, etc.

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm already applying corners to the image. Isn't working. I need to put this image on this custom view. The view should be rounded, with shadow, and have an image inside.

Comment: Post edited. Please take a look on the expected result I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Updated with full extension

Comment: WORKED! Ty very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the image in and give it a few attributes to make it round.
When you have the UImage selected click on the attributes tab and click on the '+' and type in

```
layer.cornerRadius
```

And change it to a number instead of a string. All number 1-50 work. If you want a perfect circle then type in 50.

Comment: I'm already doing this. Check the last part of the code. Isn't working that way :(

Comment: just edited the post adding the expected result. Please, take a look. PS: I'm not applying cornerRadius to the view on storyboard because that kills the shadow layer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the following below `super.layoutSubviews()`:

```
self.clipToBound = true
```

What is ClipToBound?

clipsToBounds property

> A Boolean value that determines whether subviews are confined to the
>   bounds of the view.
>
> Discussion Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to
>   the bounds of the receiver. If set to NO, subviews whose frames extend
>   beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default
>   value is NO.

Comment: The image layer already have imgLayer.masksToBounds = true. Isn't working. This should work on this custom view. The view should be rounded, with a shadow layer, and have an image inside.

Comment: I'm talking about clipToBounds, no masksToBounds (Here is the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39466262/4077559) . I just edited my answer @CharlesPrado

Comment: just edited the post adding the expected result. Please, take a look. PS: I'm not applying cornerRadius to the view on storyboard because that kills the shadow layer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to remove the :

```
let imgLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let myImage = image.cgImage
```

And replace the code with:

```
Image.frame = bounds
Image.masksToBounds = true
Image.contents = myImage
Image.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 14).cgPath
Image.cornerRadius  = 14
```

Xcode might not be liking the alias that you giving the image.

Then you also need to write in the brackets for the UIView

```
Layer.addsublayer(Image)
```

Comment: but the image is an UIImage... not an UIImageView. and that way the image is not being add to the view :(

Comment: In the UIView write, 'layer.addsublayer(Image)' do not write it in the same brackets with the image attributes